# Converting .Docx with images to Rmarkdown not working well

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a word document with notes from a class. In this document there are images (screenshots from the lecture). I am hoping to make a book, hopefully in bookdown, to help me organize my notes and my R code. I used pandoc to convert the word document and extracted the images, but only some of the images are showing up when i knit the markdown output in RStudio.  Any idea why some would show and some wouldnt? COuld it be because i'm changing the .md that pandoc gives to .rmd and they just dont play well together?

Comment: Hello. It is really hard to diagnose problems and suggest solutions without a simple working example that demonstrates the issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidance on how to produce a minimum reproducible example that will help others to help you.

Comment: The problem is more likely to be with *pandoc* than with *rmarkdown*, and the title could be edited accordingly. You could try to test its ouptout in a markdown viewer : https://markdownlivepreview.com/ for instance.